# How to display out of stock on product?

Tags: magento2, msi

How can I display "Out of stock" in the product based on the Warehouse selected.
I will have a selected_opco cookies that can determine the selected source.

How can I display "Out of Stock" based on the selected warehouse, it is currently showing based on the default.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to choose an inventory source on the front-end. A source can be assigned by the administrator only while creating a shipment. Try to check MSI customer source selector extension.